# library rt not found on Mac, while configuring sfft (sparse fast fourier transformation)

Tags: c, macos, static-libraries

I'm a green hand, and apology for the following could be simple question: 
I'm trying to install the package 
[sfft](http://spiral.net/software/sfft.html) on my Mac (OS X YOSEMITE). 
The configuration step halts and give an error:

`checking for library rt:not found`

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`librt` is a thing on Linux but not on OS X.  You don't need it.  Try editing the `wscript` file in the package you downloaded and remove this line:

```
conf.check_cxx(lib='rt', uselib_store='RT')
```

Then remove `RT` from `common_use` in the same file and try to build.

Comment: Thanks, that helps! Only now it's asking for "ippvm, ipps, pthread".

Comment: Well IPP is Intel Performance Primitives, so you should install those.